# Picking a city and display content

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

am new to web development i have developed one website and now i want to place a text field on top corner and give options to pick a city and display content based on selected city. for example: in a web page i should have a text box, if i enter some city name it should display tat cities contents (use case: if i select Delhi it should display Delhi's content, if i select Mumbai it should display Mumbai's content how can i achieve this task ) any code, any references can be appreciated, Thanks in advance. (HTML, javascript, java anything is ok)

Comment: This is too broad ... unless you post something on what have you written so far

Comment: Here's [HTML reference](https://www.google.by/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiqr6TXsMjVAhXlFJoKHZg_AMsQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2FTAGs%2F&usg=AFQjCNGj_GJ_jj0hAVN2pDJ98MzmoeNOPw). Hope that helps =)

Comment: @Jeyaprakash ............. https://www.nearbuy.com/     Just open this link, 1st it will ask you to pick location then it proceed further,  Here how they are selecting a city and displaying that particular content. This is what i am looking for

Comment: @IvanPronin No bro that is just html tags reference page please see comment for more explaination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something like what you want, you can make a popup instead of a dropdown if you want. Tell me if you need anymore help, or need to understand the code. This code is based of Dmitriy Lishtvan's answer for this question. I just made it relate to your question.

```js
$(function(){
          $('.selectOption').change(function(){
            var selected = $(this).find(':selected').text();
            //alert(selected);
            $(".desc").hide();
             $('#' + selected).show();
          }).change()
});
```

```css
.desc {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectOption">
<option>--Choose One---</option>
    <option>Chennai</option>
    <option>Washington</option>
    <option>Hamburg</option>
    </select>
    
    <div id="changingArea">
        <div id="Chennai" class="desc"><iframe height=900 width=900 src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chennai"></iframe></div>
        <div id="Washington" class="desc"><iframe height=900 width=900 src="https://www.washingtonpost.com"></iframe></div>
        <div id="Hamburg" class="desc"><iframe height=900 width=900 src="https://www.tripadvisor.com/Tourism-g187331-Hamburg-Vacations.html"></iframe>
</div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Hi @Riz-waan Thanks for your effort, It is not working i mean because of display: none property if i remove this property it will show everything (Chennai, Washington, Hamburg). how to display particular div contents.

Comment: @Baasu Try this https://jsfiddle.net/3anz8hwn/ It seems to work for me. Also if my answer helped, I would appreciate a upvote, thanks

Comment: @Baasu Also you need to wait while the remote page is downloaded. On my computer I had to wait for about 3 seconds and then it loaded.

Comment: Yea its working Thanks bro.

Comment: you just add iframe) that was my answer) and author don't understand that?)))

Comment: @DmitriyLishtvan Yea you are right I just expanded upon your answer to make it easier for hime to see whats going on. I gave your answer a upvote because it was technically your idea. I didn't have enough rep to comment so I just wanted to show him a way on how it would work with his needs, sorry about that

Comment: no problem) i hope he  understood

Comment: @DmitriyLishtvan I also edited the question to give you credit)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/XCUDF/`
```

Comment: https://www.nearbuy.com/     Just open this link, 1st it will ask you to pick location then it proceed further,  Here how they are selecting a city and displaying that particular content. This is what i am looking for

Comment: Ur reference link is some what similar thanks for that but i want some thing like nearbuy.com ..... Can you please figure out how to do like that

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XCUDF/248/

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can use the TextField class to have the user input. Then you can use a JButton and then when the user clicks the button the corresponding content(Organize the content with an array). 
Link to info about TextFields
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html

Also JButton
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html
Good Luck!

Comment: Your method is too much complex to develop. I am looking for simple Html Javascript code.